# How to use QSGClipNode with custom geometry?

Tags: qt, qtquick2, clip, scenegraph, qsgclipnode

How to use QSGClipNode with a custom geometry?
This is a sample:

[image]

Comment: What exactly the problem with using `setGeometry(QSGGeometry *geometry)`?

Comment: I don't know how to use `QSGClipNode` and official documentation is poor. So this question will be a reference for anybody whom wants to know how to do clipping in the scenegraph within QQuickItem in a CORRECT WAY.

Comment: It's your question that is poor for StackOverflow. What have you tried? Any code to reproduce the problem? What was the error or the desired effect? Here is an example with `QSGGeometryNode`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html

Comment: Do you tried to use `QSGClipNode`?! It is different from `QSGGeometryNode`. My question is very simple and clear... "how to use QSGClipNode?" Have you any sample code which uses `QSGClipNode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QSGClipNode**

The `QSGClipNode` uses its geometry to clip rendering of its children nodes.

So to use it, you first have to create the geometry (set of vertices/triangles) representing your mask, and set it with the `setGeometry` method. Resources are scarce yes, here is a few examples using `QSGGeometry`, that you need to draw your "heart" shape:

- an example creating a custom geometry using QSG : [QQuickPolygon](http://gitlab.unique-conception.org/qt-libraries/lib-qt-qml-tricks/blob/36a9fda3d0e00fc0ec089c188ac998cb86aa06fa/src/qquickpolygon.cpp)
- an [old presentation I made](https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/2013/sites/default/files/presentation_pdf/GraphicallyAcceleratedQtQuickComponents.pdf) (a bit surprised it shows up in google first results)
- and an example [from Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-customgeometry-example.html)

Then use the [`appendChildNode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsgnode.html#appendChildNode) method to add the children that you want to clip in your QSGClipNode. In your case, [`QSGImageNode`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsgimagenode.html) is probably the way to go, to show your image clipped.

**Other solution: OpacityMask**

Another solution, available without digging into c++ scene graph classes, is to use an `OpacityMask` from `QtQuick.GraphicalEffect`. It also applies to a QtQuickItem you would have created in C++.

The [example in Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-opacitymask.html) is easy to use, just don't forget to set the `visible` property of both the Mask and the Source to `false`, the `OpacityMask` element itself will display the source cropped/masked.

Here is a way to clip "children" with it (NB: untested at that time):

**clipperitem.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    // Item-based children will be mapped to this property
    default property alias clippedContent: clippedItem.children

    // Optional mask property to set it from outside
    property alias mask: opacityMask.mask

    Item {
        id: clippedItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id: defaultMask
        // Your default mask
        visible: false
    }

    OpacityMask {
        id: opacityMask
        anchors.fill: clippedItem
        source: clippedItem
        mask: defaultMask
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
ClipperItem {
    // Content here will be clipped. Non item-based elements will have
    // to be explicitly assigned to `ressources` property (i.e. Timer, etc.)
    Rectangle {
        //...
    }
    Image {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I test it and it clips its child node. Is there any way to clip child QQuickItems? Assume in QML `MyClipItem { width: 45; height: 45; Rectangle { id: rec; width: 50; height: 50; color: "red"; radius: 20 } }` Is it possible to clip `rec` using `MyClipItem`?

Comment: Good, I would assume it works directly as in your case, your Rectangle is reparented to `MyClipItem`. Have you tried it alredy ?

Comment: I tested it and it works perfect for `QSGNodes` as children but in earlier comment, my Rectangle named `rec` is not clipped. In other words QSGClipNode not clips QQuickItems children such as `rec`.

Comment: Please try with MyClipItem { clip: true; /*...*/ }, this should do the trick !

Comment: Ok right, that's actually normal. I edited my answer to include the OpacityMask, which might be helping to you, even though in that case you don't need a `GSGClipNode` anymore. It's however completely possible to use a QSGGeometry in a QQuickItem as the mask

Comment: OK thanks, first section of your answer is the actual answer for my question. Also your alternate solution for clipping using GLSL works perfectly. After testing your first approach I found out that It doesn't clips QQuickItem children. So I'm interested to find a way to clipping children QQuickItems as normal rectangular clipping through C++ but with a custom shape. So I can use it in QML as an Item named: `ClipperItem`

Comment: I included an example of how this could be achieved using `OpacityMask`

Comment: Thank you @Adrien